# Count repeated numbers in a file

Tags: arrays, c, file

So I'm having this file **myFile.txt** with the following numbers in it: `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 2 3 4 5 6 6 5 4 3 2 1`. I'm trying to write a program that calculates how many times a number from `0` to `9` is repeated, so it would be printed out like that `Number %d repeats %d times`. Right now I'm stuck at printing out the n number of elements of that file, so in example, if I would like to calculate how many times the 15 first numbers repeat themselves, firstly I would print out those 15 numbers, then the number of times each number repeats. But when I'm trying to print out those 15 numbers, it prints me this: `7914880640-10419997104210821064219560-1975428800327666414848`.

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("myFile.txt", "r");
    char c;
    int n, i, count = 0;

    for (c = getc(fp); c != EOF; c = getc(fp)) {
        if (!(c == ' '|| c == '\n'))
            count = count + 1;
    }
    printf("The amount of numbers is:%d\nTill which element of the list would you like to count the amount of the each element: \n", count);
    scanf("%d", &n);
    int a[n];
    if (n <= count) {
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            fscanf(fp, "%d", &a[i]);
        }
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            printf("%d", a[i]);
        }
    } else {
        printf("Error");
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There are multiple problems.  You don't end print statements with a newline; you should.  Error message _should_ be reported to `stderr`, not `stdout`.  You don't separate your outputs; using `%d` with `printf()` does not add any spaces.  You probably need to distinguish between digits (any single character between `'0'` and `'9'`) and numbers (sequences of one or more digits).   Are you trying to track digits or numbers?  Digits is far easier — not least because there are no overflow risk (there are only 10 different digits).

Comment: Always check the value returned by scanf.  In this case, you don't call `scanf` until you are at the end of the file, so scanf is most likely returning EOF and not assigning a value to `n`.

Comment: Your first `for` loop reads to EOF; you don't rewind, so the next `for` loop doesn't read anything; the file is already at the end.

Comment: since `n` is not initialized `int a[n]` is undefined behavior.

Comment: The `scanf("%d", &n)` should initialize `n`, @WilliamPursell.  I grant that there should be error checking on the `scanf()` itself and the value it assigns to `n`, but in the ordinary course of events, it'll be initialized.

Comment: You're assuming that everything in the file that isn't a blank or newline is a digit.  That isn't necessarily a good idea.  You might want to use `isdigit()` from `<ctype.h>`.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to count the numbers of digits.
How could I use this `isdigit()` in this case, could you please show me so I could understand it better?

Comment: Suggest using tracking array, such as `int track[10] = {0};`.  As you iterate through the values in the collection, increment the contents of the corresponding array element, eg, `if(ch >= '0' && ch <=9) track[ch-'0']++;`

Comment: [isdigit()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_isdigit.htm)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler THANK YOU, I've been sitting there trying to figure it out with no success, untill I remembered that there is this `rewind()` command. I've put it right under the `for` you was talking about

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the final solution.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>

int count_occur(int a[], char exist[], int num_elements, int value)
{
    int i, count = 0;
    for (i = 0; i<num_elements; i++)
    {
        if (a[i] == value)
        {
            if (exist[i] != 0)
                return 0;
            ++count;
        }
    }
    return(count);
}

int main()
{
    int a[100],track[10];
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("myFile.txt", "r");
    char c,exist[20]= {0};
    int n,i,num,count=0,k=0,eval;
    for (c = getc(fp); c != EOF; c=getc(fp))
    {
        if (!(c==' '|| c=='\n'))
            count=count+1;
    }
    rewind(fp);
    printf("The amount of numbers is:%d\nTill which element of the list would you like to count the amount of the each element: \n", count);
    scanf("%d", &n);
    if (n<=count)
    {
        while(fscanf(fp, "%d", &num) == 1)
        {
            a[k] = num;
            k++;
        }
        for (i=0; i<n; i++)
        {
            printf("%d ", a[i]);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Error");
    }

    fclose(fp);
    if (n<=count)
    {
        for (i = 0; i<n; i++)
        {
            eval = count_occur(a, exist, n, a[i]);
            if (eval)
            {
                exist[i]=1;
                printf("\nNumber %d was found %d times\n", a[i], eval);
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```